# Initialize a Blockly Mutator within JavaScript

Tags: blockly

**Hi,**

as far as I know, custom blocks in Blockly can be defined wether in JSON or in JavaScript, but how can a mutator be initialized in JavaScript?

**with JSON:**

```
Blockly.defineBlocksWithJSONArray([
{....
"mutator": "myMutatorName"
});
```

Then the Mutator_MIXIN must be defined and with `Blockly.Extension.registerMutator('myMutatorName', Blockly.myMutator_MIXIN, null, null)` the mutator is added to the Block.

**with JavaScript:**

```
Blockly.Blocks['blockName'] = {
 init: function() = {
   ....
   ??? this.setMutator(???)???
   };
}
```

So how can this be done in JavaScript?

Kind regards

a new one

Comment: In general, we are strongly preferring the JSON block definition language, in place if the older JavaScript mechanism. However, Luv's answer is correct for the old JavaScript API.

Answer (score 4):

I might be just a little bit late here, but I'll leave the answer anyway for those who need a bit more concrete example.

In JavaScript, you don't actually need to bind a mutator to your block, you just need to define `mutationToDom()` and `domToMutation(xmlElement)` functions, like so:

```js
Blockly.Blocks['my_custom_block'] = {
  init() {
    // Define your basic block stuff here
  },
  // Mutator functions
  mutationToDom() {
    let container = document.createElement('mutation');

    // Bind some values to container e.g. container.setAttribute('foo', 3.14);

    return container;
  },
  domToMutation(xmlElement) {
    // Retrieve all attributes from 'xmlElement' and reshape your block
    // e.g. let foo = xmlElement.getAttribute('foo');
    // this.reshape(foo);
  },
  // Aux functions
  reshape(param){
    // Reshape your block...
  }
}
```

Blockly will automagically take care of the rest and allow you to treat your block as dynamic one.

And if you need to used Mutator Editor UI, you must define `decompose(workspace)` and `compose(containerBlock)` functions and call `this.setMutator(...)` to set which blocks are used in the Mutator Editor UI, like so:

```js
Blockly.Blocks['my_custom_block'] = {
    init() {
        // Define your basic block stuff here

        // Set all block that will be used in Mutator Editor UI, in this
        // case only 'my_block_A' and 
        this.setMutator(new Blockly.Mutator(['my_block_A', 'my_block_B']));
    },
    // Mutator functions
    mutationToDom() {
        // Same as previous example
    },
    domToMutation(xmlElement) {
        // Same as previous example
    },
    decompose(workspace) {
        // Decomposeyour block here
    },
    compose(containerBlock) {
        // Compose your block here
    },
    // Aux functions
    reshape(param){
        // Same as previous example
    }
}
```

Hope that these short examples help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare how the xml is loaded to dom, and how it is saved to xml and redrawn. Also notice how it attaches a mutator to a block element in case that is the only part you need to reference a mutator already present.

```
        init: initFunction (Like you have declared.)
        mutationToDom: MutationToDom,
        domToMutation: DomToMutation,
        updateShape_: UpdateShape`
```

If all you require is to create a reference to a mutator then what you need is an element of this kind, which we will programatically create in a bit:

```
<mutation mutator_name="true"></mutation>
```

The following snippet is an example of the extra functions mutationToDom, DomtoMutation UpdateShape which attaches extra input conditionally. I have a block with a checkbox that when enabled, adds an extra input.

```
   function MutationToDom() {
    var container = document.createElement('mutation');
    var continueOnError = (this.getFieldValue('HasCONTINUE') == 'TRUE');
    container.setAttribute('continueOnError', continueOnError);
    return container;
}

function DomToMutation(xmlElement) {
    var continueOnError = (xmlElement.getAttribute('continueOnError') == 'true');
    this.updateShape_(continueOnError);
}

function UpdateShape(continueOnError) {
    // Add or remove a Value Input.
    if (continueOnError) {
        this.appendValueInput("CONTINUE_ON_ERROR")
            .setCheck('CONTINUE_ON_ERROR');
    } else {
        if (this.childBlocks_.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.childBlocks_.length; i++) {
                if (this.childBlocks_[i].type == 'continue_on_error') {
                    this.childBlocks_[i].unplug();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        this.removeInput('CONTINUE_ON_ERROR');
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `compose(..)` and `decompose(..)` methods, if you intend to update the block shape. See the docs: https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/create-custom-blocks/web/mutators